# Ctrl+Shift Arrow-Keys not working as expected

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I developed within Visual Studio as every day. Out of nothing (this is what it seems like to me) `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Up`/`Down` is not working anymore as before/expected.

Expected would be to select text. However, in Visual Studio now nothing happens anymore. In Notepad++ instead the current line is moved `Up` or `Down`.

Maybe I've pressed some magic shortcut to enable this awesome hidden feature. If so, I don't want this feature.

I really need help as of this is driving me crazy, because I don't know where this is coming from nor how I can reset this behavior.

I'm running Windows 10 (all updates installed).

I want the behavior like [here](http://www.editpad.org/). And I'm pretty sure, that this was working before. Will have to test it at my Home-PC as I am starting to going nuts on this.

Comment: Is the issue in visual studios or.. more than that?

Comment: "Notepad++ instead the current line is moved Up or Down" that's normal behaviour for Notepad++. See [Keyboard And Mouse Shortcuts](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts). To select text use <shift>+<up.down>

Comment: In Notepad++ this was never the behavior for me and I did not change anything.
Just tested in `Notepad`. Same as in `Visual Studio`: Nothing happens

Comment: <ctr>+<shift>+<up/down> does nothing in Notepad. To select text use <shift>+<up.down>

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Arrow` in apps like Word will select the entire paragraph.  But the concept of a paragraph is not part of Visual Studio, so the shortcut has been co-opted into size up or down for form controls.

Comment: @KingKerosin "I want the behavior like here" - try <ctr>+<shift>+<left/right> in Notepad and Notepad++ to get the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @DavidPostill And I'm pretty sure, that holding `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Down` was extending my selection to the next line (without unpressing `Ctrl`). But maybe it's too much work for me today. Will check at home and afterwards for mental illness ;)

Comment: @KingKerosin In VS Editor Ctrl+Shift+Down Arrow is Edit.NextHighlightedReference. See [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_edit). Shift+Down Arrow is Edit.LineDownExtend

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a case of PEBKAC ;)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> is supposed to move lines in Notepad++.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will select text.

In general, unless specific application overloads this behavior:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> enables text selection as cursor moves (either with arrows or <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> makes cursor move by words instead of characters
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> jumps to actual next page, not just next screen (ie. scrolls document to the top of next sheet of paper)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> jumps to beginning/end of the document

Comment: What happens if you open default `Notepad`, write some lines (5-6), move to line 2, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Down`?

Comment: @KingKerosin Nothing.

Comment: @KingKerosin Ctrl+Shift+Down does nothing for me in windows default Notepad.exe.

Comment: @KingKerosin Nothing in default Notepad, this http://i.stack.imgur.com/DO9Zb.gif in N++. Windows 10, Polish keyboard layout.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah... my bad